# How did Groot get his body back?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-3

When Groot fights against

> Adam Warlock

how does he get his body back?

> There is an scene where he is looking at Drax while he is lying on the floor and caress him with a little tiny branch

It seems Flora Collosus have regenerative capabilities but not sure how those apply in this case.

Comment: Why are you unsure how those apply in this case? He still has his head, so from there he can regrow his whole body.

Comment: I asked him and he said "*I am Groot*". Hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flora Colossus indeed have regenerative capabilities. And according to James Gunn, director of the *Guardians of the Galaxy* films, Groot can survive as long as his head is intact. [Gunn revealed this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1660352874222862336) in response to a fan question:

[image]

> **Question:** Just curious could groot grow that fast in 3 because his head was intact or because he didn’t do the light show in Vol 1?

> **James Gunn:** I’m not sure I understand the question - not sure what the light show in Vol 1 is - but as long as Groot’s head is okay he’s okay & remains the same Groot.